# saving and retrieving XML data using SQL server 2014 in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

My XML data should be like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
<XMLData>
<TUReportData><BureauResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RawData xmlns="https://secure.transunion.co.za/TUBureau" />
<ResponseStatus xmlns="https://secure.transunion.co.za/TUBureau">Success</ResponseStatus>
```

But instead of that your code is converting < to `&lt;` and > to `&gt;`

Retrieving the xml from the database code

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ICDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string SQL = "Select TUReportData from TUReport WHERE ConsumerID = @ConsumerID";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ConsumerID", txtIDNumber.Text));

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        dt.TableName = "XMLData";
        dt.ToString();
        dt.WriteXml("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/TUWebServiceCaller/Log/temp.xml");

// Getting file path    
        string strXSLTFile = Server.MapPath("styles/style.xslt");
        string strXMLFile = Server.MapPath("Log/temp.xml");

        // Creating XSLCompiled object    
        XslCompiledTransform objXSLTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        objXSLTransform.Load(strXSLTFile);

        // Creating StringBuilder object to hold html data and creates TextWriter object to hold data from XslCompiled.Transform method    
        StringBuilder htmlOutput = new StringBuilder();
        TextWriter htmlWriter = new StringWriter(htmlOutput);

        // Creating XmlReader object to read XML content    
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strXMLFile);

        // Call Transform() method to create html string and write in TextWriter object.    
        objXSLTransform.Transform(reader, null, htmlWriter);
        Results.InnerHtml = htmlOutput.ToString();

        // Closing xmlreader object    
        reader.Close();
```

this is the complete code but the problem is the xml code that i need the tags to be converted before i pass it through to be styled

Comment: What is your question? What do you mean by `your code is converting`? Where is your code?

Comment: Are you receiving xml from your stored procedure?  What I usually do is put this xml into an object.

Comment: I edited the question to have the code

Answer (score 0):

When you save it the xml is encoded so when you bring it back just run.

```
 string html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedXMLString);
```

I don't exactly know what the question is here but I hope this helps.

Comment: where do i put that code snippet in the code that i put above

Comment: Try reading in each line from the reader into your string builder.
You should be able to do 
    foreach(var line in reader.ReadLine()) { htmlOutput.Append(line) }

Comment: Or set Results.InnerHtml to HttpUtility.Html.Decode(htmlOutput)

Comment: So Results.InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlOutput). I hope this helps. I just recently was having troubles with this exact issue.